# Loading a common footer in HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html

http://jsfiddle.net/L7kkY/ - My jsfiddle

I am trying to load a common footer throughout my html pages, but it doesn't seem to be working. I broke my page's main body into two columns and I think that's why I can't call my footer to load into the correct area.

How can I load my footer from a separate file?

```
<div id="col1">
    <div id="footer">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        $("#col1.footer").load("footer.html");
        //]]>
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

The rest of the code can be found on the jsfiddle, I cut out everything that wasn't the footer in col1.

Comment: Is this html dynamicly loaded?, or is this in the html on hte first load?

Comment: And, why not php: `<?=file_get_contents("footer.html");?>`

Comment: It's for an assignment and we aren't allowed to use php unfortunately. :(

Comment: @Martijn I guess his file is .html and not .php

Comment: @Stormie you should use $(document).ready(). See my answer below

Comment: @Martijn just gave the hint that he can use PHP as well.. whats wrong with that? and I think PHP is a better way, instead of just rely on javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#col1.footer')` does not match any element. The correct selector is `$('#footer')`. Make sure, too, that there is only one element with this ID.

Also, put the `<script>` *after* the closing tags. Before that, the browser's DOM does not know the elements yet.

If you want classes (i.e., several footers exist), use this:

```
<div id="col1">
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#col1 .footer").load("footer.html");
//      ^--- note the space
</script>
```

Comment: When I use '$("#footer").load("footer.html");'
It changes the entire page to a blank screen with a "last updated"

Comment: Is your HTML valid? Unclosed tags might do this.

Comment: Yes, everything was validated and unchanged prior to this.

Comment: It still validates now too :c

Comment: I've put together a minimal working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/boldewyn/3NmQR/ (don't bother about that `{html...}`, it's basically what JSFiddle shall echo back). Can you determine, where your code deviates from this?

Comment: The only difference in my code (that I can see) is that my footer is in another div..

Answer (score 0):

you can do this easily using jquery.
just include this once in your webpage.

```
$(function(){
    $("[data-load]").each(function(){
        $(this).load($(this).data("load"), function(){
        });
    });
})
```

now use data-load on any element to call its contents from external html file
you just have to add line to your html code where you want the content to be placed.

example

```
<nav data-load="sidepanel.html"></nav>
<nav data-load="footer.html"></nav>
```